# Turn player On/Off using Tone.js

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I am making a square shape where I can select the square to turn my music on and then select it again to turn my music off. I have it to where the music turns on,  but how would I turn my music off?

```
function mousePressed() {
    if(mouseX >= 700  && mouseX <= 1000 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 400) {
        var player = new Tone.Player("media/test.mp3").toMaster();
        player.autostart = true;
        noLoop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `else { player.stop(); }` though player is defined within that if statement so you would have an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the member `.state` of the player object. depending on it's state you perform what you need.

```js
var player = new Tone.Player("media/test.mp3").toMaster();
player.autostart = true;
noLoop();

function mousePressed(player){
  if(player.state == "started"){
    player.stop();
  } else if (player.state == "stopped") {
    player.start();
  }

}
```